# Porting an NPAPI plugin to WebExtension

Tags: printing, npapi, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a NPAPI plugin to integrate a web application with printer. I am looking for some resources on how to port existing NPAPI plugin to new WebExtension standard.

First question is, what are WebExtension limitations so I ll evaluate if it's even possible ?

My current plugin is loaded through:

```
<embed id="myprinter" type="application/mozilla-printer-scriptable-plugin" width=200 height=200>
```

Then we can interact with the plugin using methods exposed by the object  e.g

> myprinter.print(), myprinter.clear(), myprinter.render(imageurl)

And properties

> myprinter.status, myprinter.retcode

The plugin interacts with an old version of zebra printer to print a image.

My knowledge of how current NPAPI works internally is also limited as the current extension is written by some other developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NPAPI model was a `DLL` that could be loaded and expose code directly.

This is no longer possible in WebExtension model. The closest alternative is [Native Messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) - instead of loading a DLL the browser starts a Native Host process and relays formatted messages to it through STDIO.

So in theory, an architecture would be something like this:

1. You write a Native Host "wrapper", that loads the DLL and calls its methods, and is ready to talk to Chrome using the Native Messaging protocol.
2. You write an extension with a background page that talks to the Native Host.
3. You write a content script that injects a `myprinter` object into the page's namespace with the same exposed methods, and relays the requests to the background page.

So:

Page → Injected `myprinter` → Content script → Background script → Native Host "wrapper" → DLL → Printer

Comment: This is the method that FireBreath 2 uses

Comment: @Xan, do you suggest any resources to get started with ?

Comment: @sakhunzai It's a problem with multiple unrelated skill sets required and I don't know your general level of knowledge in them. It's hard to recommend anything given this. Which parts do you need help with, and what's your level with them?

Comment: @Xan please check my related question I tired to use FireBreath as suggested by taxilian my build fails after long shot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47157225/firebreath-fbtestplugin-build-fails-on-mac-osx-10-10-5

Comment: I am currently on Mac OS X so I would like to definitely try to go through all the steps you listed above. The first obvious step is to start with `"Native Host wrapper"` as you suggested. Therefore I am starting with a example project from FireBreath. As far as I know Mac OSx dosen't support `dll`, that is the puzzle point for me

Comment: My C/C++ skills are rusty if that is what you mean,  I ll appreciate any stuff related to steps you listed above,thanks